# Issues identifying SPNs

Tags: windows-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, spn

**Background**

We are performing a server move. In the process, new servers and service accounts have been created. I'm getting two issues which I think are related to SPN's:

1. I've created some SQL Linked servers (using 'current security context', i.e. windows authentication) and I'm getting error `Login Failed for user NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGIN`, but only when I use it from a client (not when I use it when connected from the server). Double hop anyone?
2. We have a web app set up and as far as I can tell it doesn't function under Kerberos (just prompts for login then fails), but does function under NTLM

**Actual Questions**

So I'd like to try and work out exactly what SPN's have been lodged in AD but I have two issues/confusions:

*Issue 1:*

When I type `SetSPN -L MyDomain\MyServiceAccount1` I get

> > Ldap Error(0x22 -- Invalid DN Syntax): ldap_search_s

How do I get around this? Is there an AD browsing tool I can use to enumerate this? I guess it's because there is an invalid character it can't handle (there's a `$` in it but surely that's common?)

*Issue 2:*

When I check the old server I typed these two things:

`SetSPN -L ServerNameZ`

I get a list of default SPN's, but *no SQL Server ones*

i.e.

> > HOST/ServerNameZ
> >
> > HOST/ServerNameZ.domain.local

When I type `SetSPN -L MyDomain\MyOldServiceAccount`

I get the SQL Server SPN:

> > MSSQLSvc/ServerNameZ.domain.local:63267
> >
> > MSSQLSvc/ServerNameZ.domain.local:COL1
> >
> > MSSQLSvc/ServerNameZ.domain.local:59082
> >
> > MSSQLSvc/ServerNameZ.domain.local:COL2

Why doesn't the SQL Server SPN appear in the first server centric list? Isn't that meant to list *all* SPN's against the server?

Comment: Give this tool a run and see what it says. I've had good luck using it to troubleshoot SPN issues on SQL. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39046

Here is a MS blog about the tool. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/analysisservices/archive/2013/05/23/released-kerberos-configuration-manager-for-sql-server.aspx

I ran it from the local SQL server with no issues

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'd like to avoid installing things on the server but I'll give it a try if I can't find anything else in a few days.

Comment: It's not an install. you can extract the file and copy it over to the server. It's a standalone exe. Or you can connect to the server remotely with the tool somewhere else

Comment: Thanks - I was a bit nervous about the .MSI but I installed it. I managed to connect to our old servers but our new servers gave me 'Unable to access User Principal Information from the system'. It did highlight something interesting though - some of the SPN's in the old system have been registered with a port that is dynamic. Thanks for your suggestion.